# Is it possible to create an android.media.image instance from a file?

Tags: android, tensorflow

i would like create an `android.media.Image` instance with a file which is loading from the storage.
Cause i would like to do somenthing like this:

```
 final Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
 final int yRowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
 final int uvRowStride = planes[1].getRowStride();
 final int uvPixelStride = planes[1].getPixelStride();
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Which format the image from the storage has?

Comment: @DamiaFuentes jpg is the format

Answer (score -4):

try this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 5);
Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
if(img != null){
    final Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    final int yRowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
    final int uvRowStride = planes[1].getRowStride();
    final int uvPixelStride = planes[1].getPixelStride();
}
```

of course, you need to handle (missing file or wrong name/path, options and compress format)

Comment: Where do you got this Class "MemoryStream" ? Android Studio is telling me that he cannot resolve symbol "MemoryStream"

Comment: What is the point of saving `bitmap` into `stream` if you don't use it later? .... There is no at all... Then what is the point of loading `bitmap` in this code? There is no ... since we don't need it to put it into `stream` and we are not using `bitmap` object to other thing that putting it to this stream ... Recap: **reader code is not connected with loading code so this is usless**

Comment: @Selvin the problem is i cant test this code: the idea is to finally save the bitmap to file so he can acquire it from 'aqcuireLatestImage()'